# Can someone explain what is going on here?

Tags: scala, unit-type

Here's the code:

```
scala> def foo(bar: Unit => String) = {bar}
foo: (bar: (Unit) => String)(Unit) => String

scala> foo(a => a.toString)
res0: (Unit) => String = <function1>
```

I am guessing a is of type Unit, but isn't Unit an object? Is the Unit class hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Unit` is an `AnyVal`, like `Int`. Its sole member is a literal, written as `()`. For example:

```
scala> def foo(bar: Unit => String) = {bar}
foo: (bar: Unit => String)Unit => String

scala> foo(a => a.toString)
res0: Unit => String = <function1>

scala> res0(())
res1: String = ()
```

Answer (score 4):

Working from your examples...

```
def foo(bar: Unit => String) = {bar}
```

This defines the `foo` method, which accepts a function from `Unit` to `String` as its sole argument, and simply returns that same argument.

```
foo(a => a.toString)
```

`a => a.toString` defines a function inline.  Because the type inferencer knows that a function `Unit => String` is expected at this location, it infers `a` to be of type `Unit`.

This invocation of `foo` then returns the anonymous function that you just defined.

I'm curious, what exactly were you trying to achieve here? Or were you just exploring Scala's syntax?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala `Unit` is equivalent to Java's `void`. You have defined a function that accepts another function with no parameters and returns a `String`.

This is equivalent to `def foo(bar: => String);` Or  `def foo(bar: () => String)`

In Scala `()` is a shortcut for `Unit`

Comment: My main confusion stems from the fact that I'm applying .toString to an instance of Unit. Can a Unit object be instantiated in any other way? (new Unit).toString and Unit().toString both fail.

Comment: The only way you can get an instance of Unit is "()". For example, the line "().toString" will give you the toString of a Unit instance.

Comment: @Henry, anything you pass in to `res0` will be of type `()`. What are you trying to do? Because given what you have will always return `String = ()`

Comment: @Amir I was just playing around with function definitions and I thought it was rather weird you could instantiate the Unit class.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Kevin Wright is entirely correct, but to break it down further:

The first line is declaring a function called `foo`. `foo` takes as its argument another function, `bar` that itself takes in `Unit` and returns a `String`. Generally speaking, `Unit` in scala has the same meaning that `void` does in many other languages, so you could say for the most part that `bar` is a function that takes in no arguments and returns a `String`.

The body of the `foo` function simply returns the argument it received. Therefore, scala infers that `foo` returns a function that takes `Unit` and returns a `String`.

The second command calls `foo` with the function `a => a.toString` as its argument. `a` is assumed to be of type `Unit`. If `Unit` was an exact analogue to `void`, this wouldn't work. You can't call `toString` on the absence of something. However, `Unit` behaves slightly differently, exactly for situations like this, and `a` will be given an instance of `Unit`. This instance won't really be able to do much, but it will be able to have `toString` called on it. So the result of the second command will be a function that returns the result of `toString` called on the `Unit` instance, which is:
"()"

Comment: In my browser, my answer appears *below* yours.  From personal experience, it's safest to quote posters' names if referencing other replies.